# Updating the Z-Order of Many Windows Using Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, z-order

The scenario is that I have a list of window handles to top level windows and I want to shift them around so they are arranged in the z-order of my choosing.  I started off by iterating the list (with the window I want to end up on top last), calling `SetForegroundWindow` on each one.  This seemed to work some of the time but not always, improving a little when I paused slightly in between each call.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Edit:

It looks like the `BeginDeferWindowPos`/`DeferWindowPos`/`EndDeferWindowPos` route is the way to go.  However, I can't seem to get it to work with more than one window at a time.  When I limit the window list to a single window, it works correctly.  When the list has multiple windows, it only seems to get one of them.  Here is pseudo code of what I'm doing:

```
HWND[] windows;
HWND lastWindowHandle = 0;
HDWP positionStructure = BeginDeferWindowPos(windows.length);

for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
{
    positionStructure = DeferWindowPos(positionStructure, windows[i], 
        lastWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
}

EndDeferWindowPos(positionStructure);
```

I'm sure it's something small/obvious I'm missing here but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a special set of api's for setting window positions for multiple windows: [BeginDeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632672%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) + DeferWindowPos + EndDeferWindowPos (SetWindowPos in a loop will also work of course, but it might have more flicker)

Comment: +1: this is definitely the better route, especially if you're dealing with a large number of windows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this does seem like the right approach to take.  See my edit of the question for the problem I'm running into with it.

Comment: @Greg Shackles: You probably want SWP_NOACTIVATE, and maybe SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) to order your top-level windows.

```
// Hypothetical function to get an array of handles to top-level windows
// sorted with the window that's supposed to be topmost at the end of array.
HWND* windows = GetTopLevelWindowsInOrder();
int numWindows = GetTopLevelWindowCount();

for(int i = 0; i < numWindows; ++i)
{
    ::SetWindowPos(windows[i], HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

Comment: Good call, I hadn't noticed that SetWindowPos also had a parameter for z-order.  Do you know if this will suffer from the same timing problems I mentioned with SetForegroundWindow?

Comment: Try it and see if it performs better than `SetForegroundWindow()` :-)

Comment: I plan on it, I just can't do that until later.  Will report back later with the results :)

Comment: `SetForegoundWindow` does more than change the Z-order.  It "activates" the window, which has an effect on things like focus, which requires messages to go flying through the system, which is probably why the timing seemed critical.  Use `SetWindowPos` as In Silico recommends, at least for the first n-1 windows.  Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may want to do `SetWindowPos` on the final window.