# SetWindowPos not setting Z order properly

Tags: c, windows, winapi, window, setwindowpos

I am working on a window manager. Here is some code to stack windows diagonally:

```
void stack_windows_diagonal(HWND* windows, int width, int height){
    if(windows == NULL) return;

    int size = 0;
    for(;windows[size]; size++);

    RECT scr_dim;
    scr_dim.left   = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
    scr_dim.top    = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
    scr_dim.right  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    scr_dim.bottom = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

    int xoffset = 40;
    int yoffset = 40;

    int startx = (scr_dim.right - width) / 2 - (((size - 1) * xoffset) / 2);
    int starty = (scr_dim.bottom - height) / 2 - (((size - 1) * yoffset) / 2);

    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        bool success = SetWindowPos(windows[i], i == size - 1? HWND_TOP : windows[i - 1], startx + xoffset * i, starty + yoffset * i, width, height, 0);
        if(!success) {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to reposition window. Error code: %lu\n", error);
            continue;
        }

        if(i < size - 1)
            continue;

        success = SetForegroundWindow(windows[i]);
        if(!success){
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if(GetLastError())
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bring window to top. Error code: %lu\n", error);
        }

    }

    free(windows);

}
```

`windows` is terminated by NULL. Currently, this is only used for managing file explorer windows. The appear at the right x y coordinates, but the Z order is often very wrong. I get the same result setting all windows to HWND_TOP. The order they appear in is sometimes correct, but it seems very random. Why is this?

EDIT: Image showing the issue:

[image: They are overlapping eachother in the wrong order]

Comment: Hmm. What will `windows[i - 1]` refer to when the loop runs with `i == 0`? Maybe not the cause of your problem, though, if you've also tried with `HWND_TOP` for all windows.

Comment: Also, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283922/10871073) useful.

Comment: Another thought: Should your `windows[i - 1]` actually be `windows[i + 1]` ??

Comment: I currently don't have the resources to run a test but, thinking a bit more about this, I'm fairly sure that changing `windows[i - 1]` to `windows[i + 1]` will be the fix. As it stands, you have undefined behaviour on the last run of the `for` loop (trying to access `windows[-1]`) and, for other non-initial runs of the loop, the window you are referring to as the "insert after" will have an (as yet) unspecified z-order.

Comment: @AdrianMole You are right, this is a typo! However, the z order still is wrong after fixing it. Sometimes, not all windows are brought to the top, and sometimes they are, but even then they might be in the wrong order.

Comment: Window positioning is asynchronous, so I suspect the issue is simply that things are happening out of order at times. You could try putting a Sleep() in after the call to SetWindowPos to see.

Comment: @AndreasSandberg Have you tried using `HWND_TOPMOST`?

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Yes, but the problem is that it stays focused even if you click another window then. I want to bring them all to the top in order, but not have them force the system to make them stay on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jonathan Potter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506413/jonathan-potter) said, window positioning is asynchronous.

Putting a `Sleep()` in after the call to `SetWindowPos()` works.